# How do I disconnect this AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How can I close this connection and Asynctask if url doesn't exist. Please kindly help me .

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DownloadFile().execute("https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4kCo.jpg");
}
```

Download task is below and I can't control it to be stopped, progress is started and still showing if url is invalid.

```
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Long> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);// Change Mainactivity.this with your activity name. 
    String strFolderName;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL((String) aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            String targetFileName="downloadedimage.jpg";//Change name and subname

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myImage/";
            File folder = new File(PATH);
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdir();//If there is no folder it will be created.
            }
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(PATH+targetFileName);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                       publishProgress ((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
         if(mProgressDialog.getProgress()==mProgressDialog.getMax()){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Completed !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

All required permissions added properly.

Comment: Use cancel() method to disconnect your AsyncTask, if you want more details I will provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cancel()` on the `AsyncTask`. Any calls to `isCancelled()` after that will return true. This doesn't necessarily mean your `doInBackground` method will stop executing. You have to manually check `isCancelled()` during that method to exit gracefully. Although once you call `cancel()`, `onPostExecute()` will not get called. `onCancelled()` will get called however.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your code

```
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

protected Boolean doInBackground(String... aurl) {
```

Now when you url fails on `doInBackground` method just `return false` from there

Now you can check this on

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(!result){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
    }
```